# Git показывает все файлы, как измененные

Tags: node.js, git

Столкнулся с непонятной проблемой. Я использую windows и WSL для разработки.
Скачиваю проект с гита, по началу все нормально, ветки переключаются без проблем, но как только я делаю npm install и запускаю через nodemon, начинаются проблемы.

Git начинает показывать файлы, которые я не затрагивал, как измененные. Иногда некоторые, иногда сразу все. При попытке открыть файл, сделать коммит или stash, я получаю предупреждение о том, что permission denied.

Я полагаю, что эта проблема именно из-за использования WSL, но без него проект попросту не запустится, т.к. под винду нет некоторых библиотек. Ставить линукс не буду, полагаю, что есть решение данной проблемы.

Подробно, что я делал:
-Через терминал linux я делаю git clone, npm install, bower install и nodemon. Работаю через VS Code из под винды, и он начинает меня спамить о том, что файлы изменены (которые нельзя даже открыть, как я указал выше). Далее работа встает.

Git for Windows видит то же самое, и так же ругается, что не имеет жоступа, чтобы хоть что-то сделать.

Comment: crlf, crlf, crlf

Comment: Возможно ваша проблема из-за того что git по умолчанию отслеживает изменение прав на файл. Чтобы убрать надо в репозитории выполнить 'git config core.filemode false'

Comment: показывайте, что за изменения обнаруживает программа *git* в ваших файлах (небольшую выдержку из вывода `$ git status` и `$ git diff`

Comment: Permission denied - при попытке открыть файл в VSCode. Если написать git diff в bash, то ошибок с правами нет, но и изменений каких-то не видно, просто кусок файла, выделенный красным цветом (так, словно он был изменен весь).